# Deserialize a list with one element, directly as the element itself in case the list size is 1 (Json format)

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, serialization

In a Spring Boot application, I have a DTO class called Resource.java containing a list of strings. Inside a GET REST webservice when I return the Resource object if the list has the size equal to 1, I want it to be deserialized directly as the String itself and not as a list with one element.

I have already taken care of the serialization for this case by using @JsonFormat(with = JsonFormat.Feature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY).

Is there anything which does a similar job for deserialization?

```java
@Data
public class Resource {

    private String id;
    private String name;
    @JsonFormat(with = JsonFormat.Feature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY)
    @JsonAlias({"foo", "foos"})
    private List<String> foos;
}
```

Current:
{
    "id": "22",
    "name": "tom",
    "hookUrls": [
        "http:blabla"
    ]
}

Desired:
{
    "id": "22",
    "name": "tom",
    "hookUrls": "http:blabla"
}

Comment: May I ask why you want to achieve this? It's quite unusual / surprising to see such an API. If something may contain more than one value it should always be a list to be honest. You even have to enable specific mapping features to support this

Comment: There is an already existing API which uses the Resource with a String foo, instead of the list from my example. But I need to adapt this API for some new clients that want to append multiple foo values in there, but at the same time I need too keep it unchanged for the old clients' requests.
In case the solution for this is too complicated, I will create a separate Resource DTO that has the list foos, and will be used in a new v2 API for the new clients.

Comment: [This](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializationFeature.html#WRITE_SINGLE_ELEM_ARRAYS_UNWRAPPED) serialization feature should work for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable the `WRITE_SINGLE_ELEM_ARRAYS_UNWRAPPED` feature which behaves exactly like you described. See [here](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializationFeature.html#WRITE_SINGLE_ELEM_ARRAYS_UNWRAPPED).

You will need to create your own `ObjectMapper` for this. To override Spring's default `ObjectMapper` just define a `@Bean` in a `@Configuration` class that returns the `ObjectMapper`with the given feature enabled.

Comment: Is there any way I can limit this configuration only to the specific list field from my Resource bean? I don't want to change the logic of the ObjectMapper for all the other beans.

Comment: You can also pass the feature to `JsonFormat.Feature` like you did with `ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY`

Comment: See [here](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat.Feature.html)